# Significant delay for serial to ethernet (TCP) byte transmission?

Tags: c#, tcp, serial-port, udp, ethernet

I am attempting to measure the roundtrip times for data transmission over Ethernet and serial port using a device that I developed on Raspberry Pi and coded in C++. I coded a C# program that sends out a single byte (baud rate = 9600) at a time to the Raspberry Pi and measures the time it takes to receive that byte back. In each of the scenarios I establish the UDP or TCP connections before the actual testing begins.

Here are my four scenarios:

1. Send one byte via Ethernet and receive back via Ethernet
2. Send one byte via Ethernet and receive back via Serial
3. Send one byte via Serial and receive back via Ethernet

For test 4, the Raspberry Pi device was not used; rather, the serial ports on the computer with the C# testing program are directly connected.

4. Send one byte via Serial and receive back via Serial

For each "Ethernet" portion, UDP and TCP were tested, and here are the average results (over thousands of data points - 10 trials of 1000 points each):

1. a. UDP to UDP: <1ms
   b. TCP to TCP: <1ms
2. a. UDP to Serial: ~5ms
   b. TCP to Serial: ~5ms
3. a. Serial to UDP: ~5ms
   b. Serial to TCP: ~62ms
4. Serial to Serial: ~6ms

I am confused as to why the Serial to TCP has such a large delay compared to the other configurations. Additionally, it always seems that the first byte sent has a round trip time of 4-5ms. After that, all the bytes have RTT of ~62 ms. Can anyone explain this or point me to a good resource? Does it have something to do with pipelining or the bottleneck between Serial and Ethernet? If so, why don't I see the same phenomenon with Serial - UDP?

The code for UDP and TCP is essentially structured the same. If you need to see the code I can upload that as well.

---

UPDATE:
I am still having trouble with this issue. I tried to disable setsockopt to TCP_NODELAY in the C++ RPi server, but this didn't really change the times. I have also looked into synchronizing times between the laptop and the RPi using NTP but I am running into a lot of issues there too. For instance, the UTC millisecond resolution on C# doesn't seem to be high enough. Also I am having issues synchronizing with my laptop and the Rpi so I prefer not to go that route. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: There's a chance it's your OS's [nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) (or similar TCP congestion reducing algorithm), but it's more likely that it's your code that shuttles the data from one to another. Are you calling `Flush` immediately after writing the byte to the TCP socket?

Comment: Sending single bytes across a network is very slow, the latency will kill the transmission rate.  So any such converter will have to do something about it.  All they *can* do is intentionally delay the transmission so they can receive more bytes.  There ought to be a config parameter that lets you tweak that delay.  If you don't see it in the manual then keep shopping.

Comment: Windows doesn't use interrupts instead uses timers which add latency.  Passing of serial data from application level to hardware I/O is done with Timer Tick process in windows.

Comment: @LukeBriggs  I am not calling flush. Is there such a function for Linux sockets? I didn't see it in the man pages.

Comment: @HansPassant For my particular application, it needs to send it one byte at a time.

Comment: @nt387 It depends on which library you're using - if you're just using a C# Socket instance then set the [socket.NoDelay property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay(v=vs.110).aspx); this will essentially disable TCP congestion reduction and skip that delay.

Comment: @LukeBriggs On the C# side I am first writing the byte to the serial port. Then the byte is received by the Raspberry Pi via a serial interface. Then the Pi writes that byte to the TCP socket, and the byte is finally received by the C# program. The RPi server is coded in C++. In the server code I tried to setsockopt with TCP_NODELAY but it didn't really affect the times.

Comment: You don't specify the serial baud rate - what is it? Also, are the TCP connections already established before the test is started?

Comment: @barny The serial baud rate is set to 9600. Yes, the TCP connection is initiated before the actual testing begins.

Comment: @nt387 Can you explain this requirement in more detail? There seems to be absolutely no conceivable advantage to sending the bytes one at a time and lots of obvious disadvantages.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Basically in the application, the byte is sent after a specific event occurs on one system. Each byte represents a specific event, so they must be sent to the receiving system as soon as they are generated for accurate timestamping.

Comment: @nt387 If accurate timestamping is important, forcing extra latency by sending only one byte when you could send two makes *no* sense at all. How does intentionally delaying that second byte (by sending only the first one) improve timestamping?

Comment: @nt387 Try a thought experiment. Imagine if for some reason network conditions aren't perfect and no data goes through for a small amount of time. In that time, you've accumulated five bytes you want to send. Which is better, sending them all at once or sending them one at a time? So for your use case, where you care about latency for accurate timestamping, why force the obvious worst case performance by sending them one at a time?!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if i'm understanding correctly, if i send multiple bytes at once, they'll be timestamped all at the same time, which would be incorrect. for that reason, i want to send the byte the moment they are generated. why is this huge latency not an issue for the other test configurations? that's what I really want to know.

Comment: @nt387 Somehow I'm not getting through to you. Can you read the thought experiment again and really think it through. Say there's a hiccup in the link and it just so happens that you have two bytes to send by the time the link is operational -- for what possible reason would you send them one at a time? That would just make the timestamp of the second byte even less accurate.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand. You are talking about the worse case scenario, which probably won't happen most of the time. i can add the code that takes your suggestion into account in case there is a hiccup in the link, but it won't really work for the normal case right? the receiver would register two events that were sent at different times to be at the same time. I also still don't know why this huge delay is happening in the serial-tcp case, when tcp-tcp and tcp-serial was fine with single byte sending/receiving, which was my original question.

Comment: See my answer for the explanation and a workaround.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz   Thank you! Sending the reply byte made all the difference!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is sending single bytes of TCP with minimum latency. Here's a simple protocol that should optimize TCP for your use case:

First, do not disable Nagle. Second, every time the receiver receives some data, it should send a single reply byte. The sender shall receive the reply byte and discard it.

The receiver should attempt to receive at least 64 bytes at a time. Regardless of how many bytes it actually receives, it should send a single byte in reply.

This should stabilize your latency by allowing the ACKs to piggyback on the reply byte. In the vast majority of cases, the receiver will receive one byte at a time, but you need a way to recover from network or CPU issues rather than a scheme that will get disrupted by them and display progressively worse behavior.

The sender need never wait for the reply byte. It can just send whenever it can.